# how to get active users in liferay

Tags: liferay

How do I get all ACTIVE USERS in liferay?
I have used this API

```
 UserLocalServiceUtil.getUsers(QueryUtil.ALL_POS, QueryUtil.ALL_POS);
```

but this seems to give me all active and deactive users also.
I only need active users?

Answer (score 1):

I have solved that by writing an dynamic query as below. I don't know if it is correct or not. Could someone please see and answer?

```
public static List<User> getallActiveUsers() {
        List<User> activeUsers = new ArrayList<User>();
        Criterion stageCriterion = null;
        int deactiveStatus = 5;
        DynamicQuery dynamicQuery = DynamicQueryFactoryUtil.forClass(User.class);
        stageCriterion = PropertyFactoryUtil.forName("status").ne(deactiveStatus);
        dynamicQuery.add(stageCriterion);


        try {
            activeUsers = UserLocalServiceUtil.dynamicQuery(dynamicQuery);
        } catch (SystemException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        _log.info("ALL ACTIVE USERS"+activeUsers.toString());
        _log.info("ALL ACTIVE Size"+activeUsers.size());
        return activeUsers;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

After fetching the all users you can iterate through list and check the status of the each user like

if(User.getStatus().equals(WorkflowConstants.STATUS_APPROVED))